# как снова показывать элементы после скрытия?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Прохожусь по массиву, добавляю блокам скрытие, по клику на кнопку показываю по 3 блока, когда закончился список показываю кнопку скрыть и по клику блоки скрываются.

Не могу заново выполнить действие добавления.

```
var btn = document.querySelector('#more');

var data = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.content__carts .cart'))
var step = 6;
var item = 0;


data.slice(step).forEach( e => e.style.display = 'none')
item += step

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var tmp = data.slice(item, item + 3);
    tmp.forEach(e => e.style.display = 'inline-flex');
    item += 3;
    if (tmp.length < 3) {
        btn.innerHTML = 'Скрыть всё'
        btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            btn.innerHTML = 'Больше'
            data.slice(step).forEach( e => e.style.display = 'none')
        })
    }
})
```